# System of coupled ODE - heat exchanger problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, ode

I'm solving a heat exchanger problem and have to find the final temperature. It's a system of ode's I've written the following code: It asks for me to define T and t, but I they're functions of x that I should find

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

#propriedades trietileno glicol na entrada
T1 = 363 #K temperatura de entrada
Wt = 3.6 #kg/s vazão

#propriedades água na entrada
t1 = 298 #K 
Ww = 1.0
Ww = [0.1, 0.5, 1] #kg/s vazões

Di = 0.07792 #m diâmetro interno
L = 3.048 #m comprimento do tubo

U = 283.72 #W/m²K
pi= 3.1415

cpt = 1901.09#, 2.7683*T + 896.2] #J/kg*K calor específico
cpw = 4018.04#, -0.00003*(t^3) + 0.0403*(t^2) - 16.277*t + 6083.7] #J/kg*K calor específico
cp = [cpt, cpw]

def funct(y, x):   
    y = T, t
    dTdx = (U * Di * pi / (Wt * cpt)) * (T - t)
    dtdx = (U * Di * pi / (Ww * cpw)) * (T - t)
    x = np.linspace(0, L, 100)

    return dTdx, dtdx

# Vetor espaço


# Initial condition
y0 = T1, t1
sol = odeint(funct, y0 , x)

# plot
plt.plot(x, sol[:, 0], label='Trietilenoglicol')
plt.plot(x, sol[:, 1], label='Água')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('posição')
```

but it gives me the following error message :

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-2f2a81626e49> in <module>
     35 # Initial condition
     36 y0 = T1, t1
---> 37 sol = odeint(funct, y0 , x)
     38 
     39 # plot

c:\users\idril\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py in odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, full_output, ml, mu, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin, ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords, printmessg, tfirst)
    242                              full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
    243                              ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords,
--> 244                              int(bool(tfirst)))
    245     if output[-1] < 0:
    246         warning_msg = _msgs[output[-1]] + " Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information."

<ipython-input-47-2f2a81626e49> in funct(y, x)
     23 
     24 def funct(y, x):
---> 25     y = T, t
     26     dTdx = (U * Di * pi / (Wt * cpt)) * (T - t)
     27     dtdx = (U * Di * pi / (Ww * cpw)) * (T - t)

NameError: name 'T' is not defined
```

I've already read many answered questions but still can't find the mistake.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not enough of a problem description for us to help you. How does it not work? Does it give you errors?

Comment: I've eddited the code explaining it better, thank you

Comment: The error line is backwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to unpack the list in `y` into the single variables, this has to be written in the reverse direction as when you pack `y0`,

```
T,t = y
```

---

You want to define the time array `x` at the same point as y0

---

You define `Ww` twice, the second time as tuple. There are no arithmetic tuple operations. Remove that second definition if it does not serve a special purpose.

Comment: y0 has to stay the same, as it is constructed from the individual initial values. There is additional strangeness.

Comment: @IdrilValar: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem (you can do so by clicking the small check next to the answer which then turns green).

Comment: Newby mistake, sorry